# Count when value is in a column in another table

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have two tables

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | f |

and

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

What I want is a count of the number of times an ID appears from the first table **ONLY IF** if it exists in the second table. How can I do this?

Example output:

| id | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you like to show ids that do not exist in the first table?
I made it show according to the ids that exist in the first table, if you want it to show up please comment below

```
select tb7.id, COUNT(tb6.id) as count
from Table_6 tb6 inner join Table_7 tb7 on tb6.id = tb7.id 
group by tb7.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left outer join` and `count` as follows:

```
Select t1.id, count(t2.id) as cnt
From table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2 
     on t1.id = t2.id
Group by t1.id;
```